# Formal proof that $e^x$ is not algebraic

Tags: exponential-function, transcendental-equations

How do I give a formal proof that $e^x$ is not algebraic, like for example: $$\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{x^n}{n!}\notin\mathbb{C}_{\mathrm{alg}}[[x]]$$  Help appreciated!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_theorem

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention about no complex analysis!

Comment: Some conditions are due for $\,x\,$, me believes.  For example, we have that $\;e^0\;,\;e^{\pi i}\;,\;e^{\frac\pi2i},\ldots$ are algebraic...

Comment: @Don: the OP means algebraic as a function.

Comment: @Peter: that's irrelevant; that's a statement over $\mathbb{Q}$ and this is a statement over $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I misread the statement, my fault.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The notation $\mathbb C_{\mathrm{alg}}[[x]]$ is a bit unorthodox, but I presume what is meant is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb C(x)$ in $\mathbb C((x)).$

One way is to think about the rate of growth at infinity.  Suppose that
$e^{nx} + p_{n-1}(x) e^{(n-1)x} + \cdots + p_1(x) e^x + p_0(x) = 0$
for some rational functions $p_i$.  Now divide by $e^{nx}$, to get
$1 + p_{n-1}(x) e^{-x} + \cdots + p_1(x)e^{-(n-1) x} + p_0(x) e^{-n x} = 0.$
Taking the limit as $x \to \infty$, using the fact that exponential decay
beats the growth of any rational function, we get that $ 1 = 0$, a contradiction.

(This is related to the fact that $e^x$, thought of as a complex function, has an essential singularity at infinity, unlike algebraic functions.)